# How to access array of files in request with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I'm sending a request from a React frontend to Python backend, in this request i'm sending a FormData() with an array of images, like this:

```
const data = new FormData()
images.forEach(image => {
    data.append('images', image.arquivo)
})
data.append('product', JSON.stringify(product))
return recuperarInstanciaAxios(true).post(`${recuperarUrlBackend()}/products/`, data)
```

But I'm not being able to access this array of pictures in Python.
Through PyCharm evaluate, request.FILES shows me a dict with an array 'images' within.
But when I do request.FILES['images'] it returns me a single file.
This is the python code:

```
def create(self, request):
    try:
        productData = json.loads(request.data['product'])
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=productData )
        if serializer.is_valid():
            product = serializer.save()
            files = request.FILES['images']
            for image in files:
                product_image= {'image': image, 'product': product.id}
                image_serializer = ProductImage(data=product_image)
                if image_serializer .is_valid():
                    image_serializer .save()
                else:
                    raise IntegrityError('Error :' +
                                         serializer.errors.__str__())
            return Response(serializer.data,
                            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            raise IntegrityError('Error:' +
                                 serializer.errors.__str__())

    except IntegrityError as exc:
        print(exc)
        return Response(exc.__str__(),
                        status.HTTP_412_PRECONDITION_FAILED)
```

It gives me an error because files is not iterable.
Am I accessing the array in a wrong way?

Comment: Can you do a 'type(files)' to see how it is interpreting it?

Comment: what type of object is returned from `FormData()`? maybe using `.append` is replacing the value with the `"images"` *key*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in how you form the variable "files" should be something like this:

```
files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field')
```

file_field is the name of your html file

Comment: That's exactly it! There's a difference between a Dict and a MultiValueDict, and I didn't knew about that. Thank you @Pablo!